# error of undefined in service on selection

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have this method that pulls out a list of filtered data for a year. In the selection of my HTML I have two years: 2018 and 2017, by default I get the data from 2018, up there well, but when I click in 2017 and click again in 2018, I miss an error as undefined and I can not find failure.

```
getControlEstadoMes(anyo: number) {
    this.service.getControlEstadoMes(anyo).subscribe(data => {
      this.gridData = data;
    });
  }
```

This is the method on the service:

```
getControlEstadoMes(value: number): Observable<ControlEstadoMesFormateado[]> {
        let listaControlEstadoMesFormateado : ControlEstadoMesFormateado[] = [];        
        let anyos = MOCK_CONTROLESTADOMES.filter(element => element.anyo == value);
        anyos.forEach(element => {
            let controlEstadoMesFormateado: ControlEstadoMesFormateado = Object.assign(element);
            let nombreMes = MOCK_CONTROLESTADOMESES.find(x => x.id == element.mes);
            controlEstadoMesFormateado.mes = nombreMes.nombre;
            listaControlEstadoMesFormateado.push(controlEstadoMesFormateado);
        });
        return of(listaControlEstadoMesFormateado);
    }
```

This is the select on the HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="anio" [(ngModel)]="anyoSeleccionado" (change)="getControlEstadoMes($event.target.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let anyo of listaAnyos">{{ anyo }}</option>  
        </select>
```

This is the error:

```
Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined
    at eval (control-estado-mes.service.mock.ts:24)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ControlEstadoMesServiceMock.getControlEstadoMes (control-estado-mes.service.mock.ts:21)
    at ControlHorasBloquearMesComponent.getControlEstadoMes (control-horas-bloquear-mes.component.ts:29)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ControlHorasBloquearMesComponent.html:10)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:12023)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13493)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13081)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8615)
    at eval (core.es5.js:9226)
```

Comment: Try to use **filter** instead of **find**

Comment: I get the following error: The property 'name' does not exist in the type 'Meses[]'

Comment: Does **anyos** has value ? use debugger to check it.

Comment: At first, yes, but when I want to return from 2017 to 2018 again, it is when I get the error.

Comment: Test it <option *ngFor="let anyo of listaAnyos" (click)="getControlEstadoMes(anyo)">{{ anyo }}</option>

Comment: not found, i dont know what is  happened